# Linq to SQL in VS 2019 using VB.NET - Outer left join?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2019

I'm struggling to get the result I need from my linq to SQL query. I can find all of the person table records, or only the ones that have a corresponding date_table entry. This is the query I'm using, this results in only MK numbers 101 and 104 being returned. Numbers 100 and 105 are missed I guess because they don't have a valid record for today?

`Where Person_data_table.MK = Date_Table.FK And Date_Table.Allocated <> "Vacation" And Date_Table.Allocated <> "Sick" And Date_Table.Date = Today And Person_data_table.Team = "A"`

This is the table data (note Today is 15-Mar-20) - Please keep answers in VB, as C# answers don't tend to work after I have translated them! - Any help appreciated

regards

Peter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you also posted your question here.
Is your question still unresolved? You can try my code as follows. Sorry I didn't use SQL, I used class, but that didn't affect the result.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim MK100 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "100",
            .First_Name = "Mike",
            .Last_Name = "Smith",
            .Team = "A"
        }
        Dim MK101 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "101",
            .First_Name = "Dave",
            .Last_Name = "Sharp",
            .Team = "A"
        }
        Dim MK102 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "102",
            .First_Name = "Roger",
            .Last_Name = "Hands",
            .Team = "A"
        }
        Dim MK103 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "103",
            .First_Name = "Keely",
            .Last_Name = "Riller",
            .Team = "A"
        }
        Dim MK104 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "104",
            .First_Name = "Simon",
            .Last_Name = "Says",
            .Team = "A"
        }
        Dim MK105 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "105",
            .First_Name = "Eugene",
            .Last_Name = "Phillips",
            .Team = "A"
        }
        Dim MK106 As NewPerson = New NewPerson With {
            .MK = "106",
            .First_Name = "William",
            .Last_Name = "Nobody",
            .Team = "B"
        }
        Dim FK101 As NewDate = New NewDate With {
            .FK = "101",
            .Date_ = "15-Mar-20",
            .Allocated = "Job Number 1"
        }
        Dim FK102 As NewDate = New NewDate With {
            .FK = "102",
            .Date_ = "15-Mar-20",
            .Allocated = "Vacation"
        }
        Dim FK103 As NewDate = New NewDate With {
            .FK = "103",
            .Date_ = "15-Mar-20",
            .Allocated = "Sick"
        }
        Dim FK104 As NewDate = New NewDate With {
            .FK = "104",
            .Date_ = "15-Mar-20",
            .Allocated = "Job nunber 2"
        }
        Dim Person_Data_table As List(Of NewPerson) = New List(Of NewPerson) From {
            MK100,
            MK101,
            MK102,
            MK103,
            MK104,
            MK105,
            MK106
        }
        Dim Date_Table As List(Of NewDate) = New List(Of NewDate) From {
            FK101,
            FK102,
            FK103,
            FK104
        }
        Dim query = From NewPerson In Person_Data_table Group Join NewDate In Date_Table On NewPerson.MK Equals NewDate.FK Into gj = Group From subperson In gj.DefaultIfEmpty() Where (NewPerson.Team = "A") AndAlso (subperson Is Nothing OrElse ((subperson.Allocated <> "Vacation") AndAlso (subperson.Allocated <> "Sick"))) Select New With {NewPerson.MK, NewPerson.First_Name, NewPerson.Last_Name, NewPerson.Team
        }

        For Each v In query
            ListBox1.Items.Add($"{v.MK,-15}{v.First_Name,-15}{v.Last_Name,-15}{v.Team}")
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Class NewPerson
    Public Property MK As String
    Public Property First_Name As String
    Public Property Last_Name As String
    Public Property Team As String
End Class

Class NewDate
    Public Property FK As String
    Public Property Date_ As String
    Public Property Allocated As String
End Class
```

And the effect is as follows:

[image]